# How to insert Bitmap and Strings into HashMap

Tags: android, bitmap, hashmap

Well, I've been trying to insert images from the the Web into the hashmap. When I use images from drawable file,  everything goes ok. But when I try to use a `Bitmap` object and String give me this error in the `add`: `The method add(HashMap<String,String>) in the type ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> is not applicable for the arguments (HashMap<String,Object>)`

```
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

                    map.put(TAG_ID_AU, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    map.put(TAG_BIRTHDAY_DATE, birthday_date);
                    map.put(TAG_IMAGE, myBitmap);
                    map.put(TAG_DAY_LEFT, day_left);

                    productsList.add(map);
```

`myBitmap` is a `Bitmap` the rest are all strings.

**EDITED**

Sorry for this Question and Tank you for the answers, now i can put the images from the url in my modify adapter, I only needed to resolve that error.

Comment: you need to convert images into Bitmap before putting it in hashmap

Comment: You can't add bitmap object to `HashMap<String,String>`. You can store in manual `ArrayList<Bitmap>`

Comment: so this is not about puting stuff in the hashmap, but rather about putting hashmaps into an arraylist.

Comment: (therefore, post the declaration of the `productList` list)

Comment: @njzk2 `productsList` is of type `ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>`.  You can tell from the error message.

Comment: i have a modify adapter, i only needed to resolve that error, i know that's not a good question but now i have my problem solve and i can put my images in peace, Tank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you haven't posted the relevant code, from the error message it's easy to tell that the type of your `ArrayList` is wrong. It should be

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> productsList
```

instead of the current

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> productsList
```

Answer (score 1):

create your object

```
public class myProduct {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String mybitmap; 
public myProduct(String id,String name,Bitmap mybitmap){
    setId(id);
    setName(name);
    setBitmap(mybitmap); 
}
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
    public  void setName(String  name){
        this.name=name;
    }
    public String getId(){
        return this.id;
    }
    public void setId(String id){
        this.id =id;
    }
    public void setBitmap(Bitmap mybitmap){
        this.mybitmap=mybitmap;
    }
    public Bitmap getBitmap(){
        return this.mybitmap;
    }

}
```

after that add this to your activity

```
List<myProduct> list=new ArrayList<myProduct>();
myProduct mp=new myProduct("0","name..",Bitmap);
list.add(mp);
```

you can access your data like this :

```
String name=list.get(int).getName();
```

Comment: Yeah, that will not even compile. Your constructor name doesn't match your class name.

Comment: I haven't tried your code, but your constructor name (`Rdv`) doesn't match your class name (`myProduct`), so it won't compile.

Comment: oh becuse i get it from my code .. i forget to rename it.. you're right

Comment: i use these objects in every one of my lists ..i found it easy and full customizable

Comment: i have a modify adapter, i only needed to resolve that error, i know that's not a good question but now i have my problem solve and i can put my images in peace